# Source code for "tools.jar" available under jdk1.6

Tags: java, java-6, tools.jar

Can anyone please help me with getting the source code for **"tools.jar"** available under **jdk1.6**.

I searched in google and searched inside jdk6 source file but couldn't able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just download the full VM source code you will get tools.jar source along with it.
Alternatively you can always visit OpenJDK source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/

openjdk/6-b14 -> sun -> tools -> jar

Comment: Thanks alot, it contains all the jdk source i will filter out tool.jar sources from it.

Comment: If possible can you please let me know where i can find source code for “tools.jar” available under jdk1.5...